# Newly created object is not from object.prototype javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

I created a new Object like

```
var result = new Object();
```

Is this supposed to inherit from "Object" and Object. prototype?.

```
var result = {}
```

This is another way of instantiating an object.

When I checked something like `Object.isPrototypeOf(result);`
**false** is returned. But when did `Object.getPrototypeOf(result);`
I get proto of the result.
And, `result.__proto__` returns result's prototype functions but `result.__proto__.__proto__` is null.

So what can I conclude from this? Is the result object inherited from the Object or not?

If not, then how to make an object access properties from the object prototype?

If yes, why are the expected results returned either null, undefined, or false?

Comment: "*`new Object()` is supposed to inherit from "Object" and Object.prototype*" - no it's not, what made you think that? Where did you learn that (can you link your sources)? What exactly did you expect?

Comment: In that case please explain what is going on here. Thanks @Bergi

Comment: "*I checked something like `Object.prototype(result);`*" - that's throwing an exception. What did you actually check?

Comment: Just executing that line on the console returned false and not undefined.

Comment: Not sure what else you were doing, please reload the page to reset your globals. That line normally does throw a *TypeError: Object.prototype is not a function*.

Comment: How to make the result object access Object.prototype's properties is my question. That is my expectation too.

Comment: Or did you actually mean `Object.isPrototypeOf(result)`? That *does* return `false`. To get `true`, you need to run `result instanceof Object` or `Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(result)`.

Comment: I am sorry about that I have missed it, yes it is Object.isPrototypeOf(result) that returned false.

Comment: Now it gives me true. Thanks for correcting whatever I was trying to do. But is there a way to access Object.prototype from results.__proto__ ? @Bergi

Comment: `results.__proto__` is `Object.getPrototypeOf(results)` is `Object.prototype`. They're all one and the same object.

Comment: When you create a new object or a new object literal, the internal `[[proto]]` property is set to `Object.prototype`. Hence, `result.__proto__` and `Object.getPrototypeOf(result)` are both `Object.prototype`.

Comment: So if I set some value in results.__proto__ will this be persisted across all the user sessions?

Comment: No. It won't be persisted. Not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was reading about prototype and prototype pollution in medium blogs where they try to explain the vulnerabilities. So if this won't be persisted at all, I do not see any harm in this vulnerability. Or please enlighten me if I have gone wrong here. @AaditMShah

Comment: @Supraja It persists until the application is restarted. In the browser, that might be a page reload (which would often execute the same xss payload again, though); on the server that rarely happens and means the prototype pollution affects all sessions of all users.